# Angular 5 how to switch from server side rendering to client side rendering when the app is loaded

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I'm using Angular + ASP.NET core. By default, it incorporates the server-sider rendering. It's reasonable because the loading takes time. Before the app is bootstrapped correctly, a server-rendering page is really necessary.

However, I find when I click any anchor link, , instead of routing from the client side, the whole document is refreshed. It's too heavy.

I'm wondering when the app is already bootstrapped, how could I disable the server-side rendering and use the client-side rendering only?

Comment: Did you use this approach? https://github.com/MarkPieszak/aspnetcore-angular2-universal

Comment: I find I may have asked the wrong question. It seems it's due to href attribute of anchor element. I'm not sure if in Angular 5, by specifying href attribute, at clicking the anchor, the whole document is reloaded.

Answer (score 1):

It's the wrong question. The reason causing the whole document reloading is not due to server-side rendering, but due to using href on the anchor element. Instead, I should use routerLink.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options here.

**Option 1**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" (click)="functionContainingRoutingLogic()">My Link</a>
```

Note that the `href` is set to `javascript:void(0)` and the routing logic will be written in the Typescript in the function `functionContainingRoutingLogic()`. Something like this:

```
public functionContainingRoutingLogic() {
  this.router.navigate(['route_name_defined_in_your_router_config']);
}
```

**Option 2**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" 
  [routerLink]="['/route_name_defined_in_your_router_config/']">My link</a>
```

So, here you are providing the route name directly in the html

Note: if you have `href="#"` or `href="anything else"`, clicking on it will reload the same page